# drop wizard - web app directory & edit static files

Tags: jetty, dropwizard

I started app development with drop-wizard recently and a bit confusing how the whole thing works.

1. Where is the web app directory?
2. Is it possible to edit static files (JS, CSS) without needing to have a redeployment?

Thanks.

Comment: DW uses an embedded jetty that is configured through your yaml configuration/code. It is not deployed as a webapp (by default though this can be done as well), but as standalone jar file. It is also meant to be a REST server deployment, so you'd usually not necessarily have any java script files or css files (since the UI would likely be coded somewhere else)

Comment: thanks pandaadb, but I have an app with 80% REST and a small UI too!

Comment: You can do anything that you are doing in your web.xml programatically as well. So in theory there will be nothing stopping you adapting your solution to that. you could also look into this: https://github.com/rvs-fluid-it/wizard-in-a-box.

Answer (score 1):

I have looked into this a bit more and will attempt to answer your questions:

1. Where is the web app directory

DW applications are not (meant as) web applications. They are deployed as an embedded system running a jetty embedded server and listening on some port(s). Having said that, there are certainly ways of packaging the application as a web application. (see link in comment)

2. Is it possible to edit static files (JS, CSS) without needing to have a redeployment? - Yes(ish)

This depends on you, really. There is a thing called an AssetBundle. These can be used to server static resources (from the classpath usually). This however is a mechanism you could use to implement your own AssetBundle that instead of serving files off the classpath, will serve files off the regular path.

Or, you could add your regular path to the classpath on startup so that the AssetBundle works.

Or, you could implement a ServletFilter for the AssetBundle (assets are not part of the jersey ecosystem) and implement your dynamic changes in the Filter.

Most of these will require restart for a reason or another. E.g.a custom implementation of a Filter obviously requires a redeploy. The Servlet returning assets also (I believe) employs a caching strategy that might require a restart (subject to your implementation).

For your UI: There is also a DW-views project that adds the ability to create views (with by default mustache templates) that can be powered from your application and served by the same REST endpoints.

Hope that helps,

After some more checking:

You can serve static resources from the file system and modify them as you go. They will be served correctly. How to do this:

Add an asset bundle with the resource path:

```
bootstrap.addBundle(new AssetsBundle("/assets2/", "/assets"));
```

This adds the root classpath resource `assets2` and has it served statically from the endpoint `assets`.

The trick is that you have to add your file system location as a classpath resource. This can be done via arguments (or the classpath tab in the eclipse run configuration). You can google that relatively easy. However, you will have to remember that classpath resources behave differently from file system resources:

In my case I added to the classpath:

```
/home/artur/tmp/assets/
```

However, my Asset bundle serves from "assets2". Let's have a look at the file system:

```
artur@pandaadb:~/tmp/assets$ pwd
/home/artur/tmp/assets
artur@pandaadb:~/tmp/assets$ find .
.
./assets2
./assets2/test.txt
artur@pandaadb:~/tmp/assets$
```

So, in my file system location has been added as root, but assets are only served from the subfolder `assets2`

Now, all the resources that are located in assets2 can be modified at runtime and will be served by DW as a static resource.

Have fun playing around,

Artur

Comment: @pMan I added an example on how to serve static resources without having to restart/redeply